# Estimating length of result of sprintf

Tags: c++

I need to estimate the length of the string obtained on  `sprintf` operation. How can I do this. In other words, how can I avoid harcoding the value `50` in the below snippet.

```
double sum;
char* resultString;
..

resultString = new char[50]; //how can I avoid hardcoding 50 here?
sprintf(resultString,"[%e]",sum);
```

Comment: Why are you using C strings instead of C++ `string`s ?

Comment: FYI, you can also send variable in the index `[someInitializedIntVariable]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `snprintf(char *buffer, int buf_size, const char *format, ...);`. `sprintf` is unsafe.

However I read you are using C++, so I would use a stringstream like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

double sum;
std::stringstream buf(std::stringstream::in | std::stringstream::out);
std::string resultString;
..

buf << "[" << std::scientific << sum << "]";
resultString = buf.str();
```

Comment: I am getting an error `error: incomplete type ‘std::stringstream’ used in nested name specifier`

Comment: I'm doing the following, but getting an empty value for cresult. The sprintf version is working.
    `stringstream buf(stringstream::in);
    string resultString;
    buf << "[" << scientific << sum << "]"
    resultString = buf.str();
    const char *cresult = resultString.c_str();`

Comment: Fixed. Apparently you need `std::stringstream::out` for `::str();`.

Comment: You don't need `in|out`. They're the default.

Comment: I prefer stringstream to printf anytime, but sometimes when interfacing with legacy code there's no way around that. see my answer below for that scenario.

Answer (score 8):

`snprintf` returns the number of chars that would have been written if the buffer was large enough. You can call it twice, once to get the length and again to actually format your string.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to avoid all this would be to use a `std::stringstream` instead:

```
std::stringstream buffer;
buffer << std::scientific << sum;
std::string resultString = buffer.str();
```

Answer (score 2):

A nice fast way is to use a fixed-sized buffer with `snprintf`, which returns the number of characters that it would have printed if the buffer were large enough.  If that return value indicates the buffer wasn't big enough, then use `malloc()` or new with the now-known size.  A slower but simpler alternative is to look for `asprintf()`, which always allocated from the heap.  You could implement your own `asprintf()` atop `snprintf()` in a few lines.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way is not using sprintf. There are many extensible, safe ways to format your output in C++ (including, but not limited to, the standard iostreams facility). If you code in C, use snprintf.

Answer (score 0):

while using printf like function you have options to provide length for each number.

printf("%.2s",  "12345");

this example prints only first two characters. This way you can estimate/limit maximum required size.

otherwise there are many good answers suggested by others

Answer (score 0):

usually, using std::stringstream is the right answer.
yet sometimes, when interfacing C code, using printf(fmt, ...) is necessary, so std::stringstream isn't possible.
in these cases one can still format a variable length string like so:

```
static void append_format(std::string& s, const char* format, va_list vl)
{
    auto cur_length = s.length();
    auto sz = vsnprintf(NULL, 0, format, vl);
    s.resize(cur_length + sz);
    auto sz2 = vsnprintf(&s[cur_length], sz + 1, format, vl);
    assert(sz2 == sz);
}

static void example_usage()
{
   std::string s;
   append_format(s, "%s %dD world", "hello", 3); // s == "hello 3D world"
   append_format(s, ", PI= ~%f", 3.14); // s == "hello 3D world, PI= ~3.14"
   std::cout << s;
}
```

note, that this method is not type safe because printf and its clones are not type safe. but it will not cause buffer overruns for valid invocations, no matter how long the result string turns out to be